# Lifecycle for ListViewItems

Tags: wpf, listview, ui-virtualization

By default a WPF `ListView` (with a `GridView`) is virtualized. So I bind my `ItemSource` property to an observable collection in a ViewModel as I am using a MVVM pattern (with Caliburn.Micro but I guess that does not matter).

How can I have a method invoke on my item view models (the items of the itemsource) when they are *used* (in scope and represented by a UI listviewitem) by the ListView and when they are *unused* (no longer in scope and represented on the UI)?

It would be very nice to lazy load some detail data but only for visible records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a derived ListView with overridden `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` and `ClearContainerForItemOverride` methods:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        ((MyItem)item).DoSomethingOnPrepare();
    }

    protected override void ClearContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        ((MyItem)item).DoSomethingOnClear();

        base.ClearContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks promising. With so much being able with styles, behaviours etc. I forgot if I could influence the list with overrides.